# Expressão regular para coleção de palavras com curinga

Tags: regex, mongodb

Estou preso na seguinte situação: tenho um dicionário de palavras em um banco mongodb, onde cada palavra é armazenada em um documento, que tem outras informações adicionais sobre ela.

Preciso de uma expressão regular que consiga encontrar cada documento através da palavra, tendo em vista que algumas palavras no banco possuem um curinga no final (*). Quando isso ocorre, a palavra com o curinga deve ser encontrada se estiver no início da string de busca. É uma espécie de expressão regular no banco de dados, para simplificar o o registro de palavras. Assim, basta que o documento tenha apenas a parte necessária da palavra com o curinga no final para que   seja retornado quando a string de busca "casar" com a palavra. Seria inviável cadastrar cada palavra possível, além disso ser completamente desnecessário, já que muitas palavras tem exatamente as mesmas informações adicionais.

Para tornar a situação mais clara, seguem alguns exemplos:

- Se a palavra no banco for "pergunt*", o documento deve ser retornado sempre que a string de busca inicia com "pergunt" (pergunta, perguntar, perguntou, etc.)
- Se a palavra no banco for "amig*", o documento deve ser retornado sempre que a string de busca inicia com "amig" (amigo, amiga, amigável, etc.)
- Se a palavra no banco for "amor", o documento deve ser retornado sempre que a string de busca for exatamente "amor".

Preciso de uma única expressão regular que sirva para todas as situações acima (curinga no fim, sem curinga).

Se possível mostrar também uma solução para casos em que o curinga também esteja no início da palavra (*palavra*), neste caso, uma mesma expressão regular para todas as situações (curinga no início, curinga no fim, curinga no início e no fim, sem curinga).

Já agradeço antecipadamente. Vai me ajudar muito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você quer o usuário envie "pergunta" e quer que isso se transforme em uma expressão regular que valide "pergunt*"? Isso não faz sentido nenhum, para construir uma expressão regular você precisa conhecer o formato do que você está validando, "pergunta" não contém informações para isso.

Se fosse para existir uma expressão regular nesse processo, era para existir cadastrada no banco de dados. Por exemplo, se a expressão `/^pergunt/i` estivesse cadastrada, o usuário poderia enviar "pergunta", "perguntar", "perguntou", e todas essas palavras seriam validas.

`/^amor$/i` validaria "amor", mas não "amoroso", `/palavra/i` validaria qualquer string contendo "palavra", no começo, meio ou fim.

Comment: Obrigado por responder. Eu estou usando um banco de dados já pronto com as palavras nesse formato e pra evitar ter que atualizar as palavras do banco, pensei nesta solução. Conheço só o básico do básico de expressões regulares, então achei que talvez pudesse ser possível solucionar a situação da maneira que perguntei. Mas de qualquer forma, sua resposta ajudou muito. A possibilidade de atualizar os documentos no banco de dados para definir expressões regulares nas palavras será avaliada.